# Finding the number of divisors function

Tags: c++

```
int checkdiv(int num)
{
    int SqrtOfnumber,i;
    SqrtOfnumber=sqrt(num);
    int counter=1;
    for(i=2;i<SqrtOfnumber;i++)
    {
        if(num%i==0)
        counter++;
    }
    counter=counter *2;
    if(i*i == num)
        counter++;
    return counter;
}
```

**In cases of 2 numbers have the same number of divisors the output should be the one with the smallest value

Input examples

```
2           \\ test cases
1 10
1000 2000
```

Expected Output

```
Between 1 and 10, 6 has a maximum of 4 divisors.
Between 1000 and 2000, 1680 has a maximum of 40 divisors.
```

The above code Output

```
Between 1 and 10, 10 has a maximum of 4 divisors.
Between 1000 and 2000, 1680 has a maximum of 38 divisors.
```

The function is returning false number of divisors while the rest of the code work corectly, How can I fix it?

the input is a number which I want to check how many divisors it have and the output in the number of divisors

Comment: For some input, what is the expected and actual output?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the input is a number which I want to check how many divisors it have and the output in the number of divisors

Comment: Please tell us *actual* values. For example, if you input `10` what would you expect for output and what do you actually get?

Comment: The semantics of this function looks wrong; if you're looking for the number of divisors then why are you looking only as far as the square root of your input? (if you were looking for prime factors that would be ok).
I.e. 5 or 10 are perfectly good divisors of 10 but your function will never report them.

Comment: @HexedAgain I used the prime factor but it took long "Time Limit Exceed"

http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78520/finding-the-number-with-the-greatest-number-of-divisors-and-lowest-value

Comment: I noticed you multiply your counter by 2 cater for the divisors larger than sqrt(num) - forget my last comment. Though this problem probably comes about from the edge cases like squares or the number itself

Comment: @mohammed If you are looking for **ANY** divisor then the code you provided would not help since you are limiting the check to the square root of the input. I am still bothered by the fact that your are always doubling your counter, why is that?

Comment: @RedSerpent 'cause I'm check the square root so the number in the counter isn't the actually number of divisors of this number..

Answer (score 0):

The fix for the problem was use **double** for the SquarOfnumber

```
int checkdiv(int x)
{
    double SqrtOfnumber;
    SqrtOfnumber=sqrt(x);
    int counter=1,i;
    for(i=2;i<SqrtOfnumber;i++)
    {
        if(x%i==0)
            counter++;
    }
    counter=counter*2;
    if(i*i == x)
    counter++;
    return counter;
}
```